# Capturing repeating groups

Tags: java, regex, repeat, regex-group

First of all let-me warning you that I am new to REGEX and that my English isn't the better...

I am trying to capture repeating groups, just like optional headers from http protocol.

What I need is given a string get all headers (none or many):

```
GET /RESOURCE/RES1 H1:value H2:value H3:value
```

So what I've tried is something like:

```
GET /RESOURCE/([^/\s]*)(\s[a-zA-Z:/|-]*)+
```

But all that I get is:

```
Group 1 = LS
Group 2 = H3:value
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How do you want your result to be? Should all headers come be separate?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something similar using the `\G` anchor but can't individually capture repeated patterns.

```
(?:\G(?!\A)|GET /RESOURCE/)(\S+)(?: |$)
```

Example:

```
String s  = "GET /RESOURCE/RES1 H1:value H2:value H3:value";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?:\\G(?!\\A)|GET /RESOURCE/)(\\S+)(?: |$)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
  System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Output

```
RES1
H1:value
H2:value
H3:value
```

Comment: I will take a look on your solution... but first I need to study REGEX for a little more...

Answer (score 0):

You can add another capture group wrapping the last capture group and quantifier `+`. In fact you can make the current capture group as non-capturing:

```
GET /RESOURCE/([^/\s]*)((?:\s[a-zA-Z:/|-]*)+)
```

Now, capture group `2` will give you following result:

```
H1:value H2:value H3:value
```

You can get individual headers from it by splitting on space, and then colon.

Comment: I've tried that solution. However I wold like to know if I could get a variable number of groups.
But I will keep this in mind. Thank u.